# run node.js app as a service

Tags: node.js, forever

This is probably a stupid question, but I can't seem to find a satisfactory answer. I just deployed my first production-ready node.js app to a windows production server. I thought it would be a good idea to use forever.js to ensure that the app continues to run, well, forever.

But I found that, if I log off the user under which the "forever start" command was run, the processes stop, too. So I need to leave the user logged on so the forever processes will continue to run, which kinda defeats the point of forever in the first place. The forever command options only seem to have to do with redirecting process output and other basic stuff. Am I just missing something? Any info greatly appreciated.

Comment: It shouldn't stop when you log off. can you share the the command you are  are using

Comment: possible duplicate of [node.js http server as a Windows service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640987/node-js-http-server-as-a-windows-service)

Comment: Safi: The command I use is "forever start app.js" from the directory where my app.js is.
Joe: Running as a service is probably the best solution, I will look into it with the suggestions in the answer you posted.